Geopy, getting SSLError and unable to resolve
I am trying geopy to get a location's coordinates and I kept getting the following error:
GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=tokyo%2C+japan&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate signature failure (_ssl.c:1129)')))

I was working on this project in Jupyter notebook and previously it was working fine but it just stop working out of the blue. I tried my codes on google colab and the codes runs fine.
The following is the code I made. It takes in a list of location, gets the coordinate and add it into a data frame.
def getcoordinates (comp_site_list):
    df_comp_coor = pd.DataFrame(columns=["location", "lang", "long"])
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "tutorial")
    for locate in comp_site_list:
        locate_full = geolocator.geocode(locate)
        print(locate)
        newrow = {"location": locate, "lang": locate_full.latitude, "long": locate_full.longitude }
        df_comp_coor = pd.concat([df_comp_coor, pd.DataFrame(newrow, index=[0])], ignore_index=True)
    
    return df_comp_coor
    print(df_comp_coor)

loca_list = ['Manchester, England','Dallas, TX','Budapest, Budapest']
test_loca = getcoordinates(loca_list)
print(test_loca)

